# KitchenAid beater stuck on new machine

Tags: kitchen

I’ve used my machine twice.  I went to try to put a different attachment on it and the pin won’t move.

Comment: I saw there were close votes because this is about a mixer. Actually, equipment is on topic on the site, and we have taken this type of question before, so I wouldn't say it's closable as off topic. But it so happens that this exact question is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

KitchenAid recommends that you compress a warm, wet towel around the top of the attachment for 10 minutes.  Reheat the towel and repeat for another couple of minutes.  The warmth will cause the aluminum to expand, and with some wiggling, should allow you to release the attachment.